# How to remove specific numbers from list MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comma separated list of numbers in a MySQL entry 'id_user' like so:

```
127,130,150,12,4,7,8,9
```

What is the best way to find a number in this comma-separated list and (1) remove it with the comma if it's with other numbers or (2) just remove itself if the number is by itself like:

```
127
```

Then update the MySQL entry.

So if I wanted to remove 150 from the list, it would be updated in the MySQL as:

```
127,130,12,4,7,8,9
```

I want to avoid trying to remove the id '12' but end up removing the '12's in numbers like 127 or 512

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading between the lines, it sounds to me like you are storing a list of foreign keys in a comma-separated string field to represent a many-to-many relationship. This is not a good idea.

What you should do instead is create a table to store the relations.

For example, lets say you have a table called `users` and you want to store friend relationships between them. What you are doing is something like this (*N.B. I realised this is actually not a great example as I wrote the end but I'm sticking with it for now*):

```
  id  |  name  |  friends
------+--------+-----------
  1   | Dave   |  2,4
  2   | Bob    |  1
  3   | Tom    |  4
  4   | Bill   |  1,3
```

Whereas what it's much better to do is something like this:

`users`

```
  id  |  name  
------+--------
  1   | Dave   
  2   | Bob   
  3   | Tom    
  4   | Bill
```

`friends`

```
  id  |  user  |  friend
------+--------+----------
  1   |   1    |    2
  2   |   1    |    4
  3   |   2    |    1
  4   |   3    |    4
  5   |   4    |    1
  6   |   4    |    3
```

To select Dave's friends you can do

```
SELECT u.*
FROM friends f
JOIN users u ON u.id = f.friend
WHERE f.user = 1
```

...and to delete the relationship between Dave and Bob (what you want to do here), you can simply do

```
DELETE FROM friends
WHERE (
  user = 1 AND friend = 2
) OR (
  user = 2 AND friend = 1
)
```

Comment: +'d by going beyond the question, by reading between the lines. Nice :)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for an answer on how to normalize the MySQL databases. Quick question as I'm new to MySQL -- what does the u and f stand for when selecting Dave's friends?

Comment: `u` and `f` are table name aliases. Basically they make it shorter to reference each table in a `JOIN`ed query. You could just write `SELECT users.* FROM friends JOIN users ON users.id = friends.friend WHERE friends.user = 1` and it would mean the same thing. There are situations where you *need* to use aliases, but this isn't one of them and they are probably a little beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP:

```
$array = explode(',', $string);
$pos = array_search('127', $array);
unset($array[$pos]);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Or using MySQL:

```
REPLACE(column, '127,', '')
REGEX_REPLACE(column, '127$', '')
```

Get UDF REGEX_REPLACE - https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp with ^127$

Comment: if the number is 1270 it will replace it too

Comment: @jcho360 And now it should, if I didn't make an error in regex.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$string="," . $string . ",";
str_replace("127,", "", $string);
```

Or you could split the string:

```
$list=explode(",",$string);
$new="";
foreach($list as $item){
    if($item!="127"){
         $new.=$item.",";
    }
$new=substr_replace($new ,"",-1);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

As [pyrate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337343/pyrate) suggests try this in MySQL

```
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEX_REPLACE(column, '127\,?', ''))
```

using the [UDF](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)

Hope this helps